# Computer slows to a crawl at 10AM-10:06AM everyday due to nvstor64

Tags: windows-7, performance

Windows 7 x64

I have checked the task scheduler and I don't see anything that is scheduled to run during that time frame.

I have watched the task manager during the slow period and nothing it taking up much resources that would explain the slowness.

I have reviewed the event viewer and have found loads of nvstor64 event id 3 errors during that period.  It turns out that this error occurs at other parts of the day but the user isn't at the computer during those times.  The user has had the PC for a year but only noticed this problem more recently.

event id 3

Data error on device.

Device: \Device\RaidPort0
 Model: WDC WD800AAJS-60B4A0
 Firmware Version: 02.0
 Serial Number:      XXXXXXXX
 Port: 0

HP doesn't offer Windows 7 x64 drivers for this PC.

Comment: Use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to find out what is actually happening...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from [here](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/248207-14-nvstor64-event)

> MajesticJG   01-28-2009 at 05:13:07 AM

-0+
.

I figured this one out, so I thought I'd post it so others can find it when they're as frustrated as I was.

The problem was a driver version mismatch in the nForce driver set. The fix was as follows:

Boot to Safe Mode 

Use Driver Cleaner to Gut the nForce drivers 

Reboot to Safe Mode Again 

Use Driver Cleaner to Gut the nForce drivers again 

Reinstall the latest nForce driver kit while in safe mode 

Reboot to normal mode

That seems to have done it! Note that Driver Cleaner costs around US$10 right now. I know there's probably another free program that can do it, but I'd heard Driver Cleaner could handle the job and I was willing to invest $10 to get the kinks out of my system.

I hope this is helpful for someone else, 'cause it sure drove me nuts!

I wouldn't suggest paying for 'Driver Cleaner', but there are certainly many free programs out there which would do the same! :)